# Android GridView calculate background color unevenly

Tags: android, gridview, kotlin

What would a good mathematical way be to calculate following problem in Kotlin for my GridView?

So in this gridview the background patterns is:

[Red][Blue][Blue][Red][Red] etc...

Right now I have set these colors programatically but soon I might remove a button if the user doesn't have right to see this button, and then my patern will break.

How would I calculate this in the adapter in Kotlin? My code now looks like this but I wan't to get rid of the `R.color.` in the class:

```
    buttons.add(GridViewButton(R.drawable.ic_message, "Account", R.color.buttonRed,this))
    buttons.add(GridViewButton(R.drawable.ic_message, "Account", R.color.buttonBlue,this))
    buttons.add(GridViewButton(R.drawable.ic_message, "Account", R.color.buttonBlue,this))
    buttons.add(GridViewButton(R.drawable.ic_message, "Account", R.color.buttonRed,this))
    buttons.add(GridViewButton(R.drawable.ic_message, "Account", R.color.buttonRed,this))
    buttons.add(GridViewButton(R.drawable.ic_message, "Account", R.color.buttonBlue,this))
```

And

```
class GridViewButton (
    val icon: Int,
    val name: String,
    val color: Int,
    val listener: View.OnClickListener
)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question correctly but you want to have a regular pattern of 2 reds, 2 blues, 2 reds and so on? then based on the position in the list I'd just do ```when(pos % 4) {
    1,2 -> println("blue")
    0,3 -> println("red")
   }``` For getting rid of the `R.color`, just create an enum for it and then inside the GridViewButton have a function that returns you the correct asset based on the value of the enum

Answer (score 0):

After some brain crushing and with the help of a commenter I figured this out:

```
when (position % 4) {
    0, 3 -> view?.layout_button?.setBackgroundColor(mContext.resources.getColor(R.color.buttonRed))
    1, 2 -> view?.layout_button?.setBackgroundColor(mContext.resources.getColor(R.color.buttonBlue))
}
```

**Explanation:**

The `position` always starts at `0`.

So if we write this out for the buttons 1 to 4.

`0 % 4 == 0`

`1 % 4 == 1`

`2 % 4 == 2`

`3 % 4 == 3`

We set the first and last value to the color red. The second and third to the color blue. On the 5th button it will basically be the same as the 1st button